# Why can't I omit the parameter of getElementById() in the Arrow Function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say I have 3 `<img>` tags on a page, and I would like to get these as an array, so I wrote:

`let myArray = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3'].map(id => document.getElementById(id));`

... which worked well.

Then I thought, hey, `getElementById` takes exactly 1 argument. Isn't there a syntax sugar for that? So I wrote:

`let myArray = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3'].map(document.getElementById);`

... but that didn't work. I got "Illegal invocation" on Chrome.

So it's not syntax sugar then. What's behind all these?

Comment: It depends on the calling context being `document`, as you can see.

Comment: What syntactic sugar you are talking about? Destructuring, that would only work for function invocation context right?

Comment: @shakeelosmani I thought omitting parameters in lambda functions is a syntax sugar, e.g. I thought `obj.map(NAME => myfunction(NAME))` is the same as `obj.map(myfunction)`.

Comment: It is the same... as long as they are *functions*. And it's not really syntactic sugar; no more than `x` is a syntactic sugar for `(x + 0) * 1`.

Comment: Like @Amdan said it has to be in a function invocation context, but however, looking at the answer below you can apparently get it done.

Comment: @Amadan Did you imply 'getElementById()' is not a *function*? What is it, and I will be sure to search up and read more about it. **Edit** sorry, just saw your answer, you called it a 'method'. Thanks!

Comment: It's tricky. It is a function, but it is also a method ("function that is the value of a property", in this case a property of `document`). I was making a distinction between ways to invoke it: `getElementId()` is a _function call_. `document.getElementById` is a _method call_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript has a difference between "method call" and "function call". The former will set `this`, the latter won't. Syntactically, method call must be of form `receiver.method(...args)`. No dot, no method call. So, this:

```
document.getElementById(id) // method call, `this` is set to `document`
m = document.getElementById; m(id) // function call, `this` is not set
```

When you do `map(document.getElementById)`, `document.getElementById` is a function plucked from its object; when `map` invokes it, it will invoke it without the receiver, `this` will not be set, and things get bad.

There is a way to save it: `bind`, which "methodifies" a function by binding a receiver to it: `map(document.getElementById.bind(document))` should work.

EDIT: to further illustrate it:

```js
let foo = {
  bar: function(context) {
    let receiver =
      (this == window) ? "window" :
      (this == foo) ? "foo" :
      "unknown";
    console.log(context + ", `this` is `" + receiver + "`");
  }
}

function call(fn, param) {
  fn(param);
}

foo.bar("In direct call");
let baz = foo.bar; baz("When assigned to a variable");
call(foo.bar, "When passed as a parameter")
let quux = foo.bar.bind(foo); quux("When bound to foo");
```

Comment: Thanks! That explained a lot. But we did say `map(document.getElementById)` (vs just `map(getElementById)`). Shouldn't the context *document* be passed along?

Comment: Imagine you have `dog = { color: "yellow" }` and you get `paint(dog.color)`. Can `paint` know that `"Yellow"` came from `dog`? Same deal; when you pluck a property from the object, there's no telling where it came from any more. `map(document.getElementById)` is the same thing.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much! You answered the "real question" I had, without me knowing how to ask it.

Answer (score 3):

You can if you pass in `document` to `map()`'s second `this` argument, which will provide the correct context for calling `getElementById`. Not sure if this is an improvement over just using the arrow function, though.

```js
let myArray = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3'].map(document.getElementById, document)

console.log(myArray)
```

```html
<p id="img1"><p>
<p id="img2"><p>
<p id="img3"><p>
```

Comment: lol, I forgot about the optional context for `map`. TMTOWTDI :)

Comment: It should be noted that this is not some standard language feature when passing function references, it works in this case simply because the `Array.prototype.map` method was designed that way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I upvoted because it taught me there's an optional parameter for `map` to set the context.

Comment: @Lennholm I think it's understood that this is a feature of the `map` function. It's also a feature of `array.filter`, `arr.forEach`, `arr.findIndex`, `arr.find`, `arr.every`, `arr.some`, etc.